# How to pass model value to a custom directive?

Tags: angularjs

I have a textbox Role and i want to check whether role already exists in database or not on the server side for that i have created a directive uniqueRole now i want to pass the textbox value to that directive how to do that.

```
**HTML**

   <input type="text" class="role-textbox" id="rolename" name="rolename" required  ng-model="roledetails.name" unique-role send-value="roledetails.name" placeholder="{{::'placeholder.addRole.name'|translate}}">

**Controller**

    'use strict';
    define([
        'angular',
        './module',
    ], function(angular, directives) {
        directives.directive('uniqueRole', function($timeout, $q, restClientTemplate) {
            return {
                restrict: 'AE',
                require: 'ngModel',
 scope:{
         sendValue: '='
        },
                link: function(scope, elm, attr, model) {
                    model.$asyncValidators.usernameExists = function(roledata) {
                        var defer = $q.defer();
                        console.log("gng to call controller");

                        restClientTemplate.execute({
                            method: 'POST',
                            url: 'json/check/role',
                            data: roledata

                        }).then(function(response) {
                            roledata = response.results;
                            defer.resolve(roledata);

                        }, function(error) {
                            defer.reject(error);
                        });

                        $timeout(function() {
                            model.$setValidity('usernameExists', false);
                            defer.resolve;
                        }, 1000);
                        return defer.promise;
                    };
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You basically want to know how to send data to your custom directive?
If that is the case here is an example, on your input you should have something like:

```
<input unique-role data="customData">
```

Where `customData` is a property defined inside you controller that is responsible for the current view. The property should be attached to your controller through `$scope`.

Now inside the directive:

```
scope: {
    data: '='
}
```

And you would have access inside the directive through the `scope` to `data`. Keep in mind that there are 3 ways of binding data to directives, that is one of the ways, you can read more about it [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive).

Comment: i edit the code still not working still getting value as undefined please help

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="role-textbox" id="rolename" name="rolename" required unique-role send-value="roledetails.name"  ng-model="roledetails.name" placeholder="{{::'placeholder.addRole.name'|translate}}">
```

Controller add a property in the object

```
scope:{
 sendValue: '='
}
```

the `scope.sendValue` in the directive will bind to the text value in your controller

Comment: 'use strict';

define([
   'angular',
   './module',
], function (angular, directives) {
 directives.directive('uniqueRole', function($timeout, $q,restClientTemplate) {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope:{
      sendValue: '='
     },
    link: function(scope, elm, attr, model) { 
      model.$asyncValidators.usernameExists = function(roledata) {      
        var defer = $q.defer();
        console.log("value of send scope is:"+scope.sendValue);
    }            did like that  still getting value as undefined

Comment: have you bind the data in your html where use the directive element? `<input unique-role send-value="roledetails.name"  ng-model="roledetails.name" >` like this